# How to deal with microservices down when creating resources?

Tags: rest, microservices

Lets suppose I have two microservices named Players and Permissions. Everytime I send a post to `/player` endpoint to create a new player, a code in the Players microservice call a post to Permissions to create the info related to the player created.

But what if the Permission microservice is down for some seconds or minutes? I will have a Player created but no Permissions created to this player. Is there some well know pattern to deal with it? If yes, whats the name of this pattern?

Answer (score 1):

The common approach in this case would be switching to an asynchronous communication between services - for example using some message bus, i.e. instead of calling `Permissions` when user created in `Players` you will send a message to a queue which then will be consumed by some processor in `Permissions` service and will create corresponding permissions.

Also from the get go I would recommend implementing [transactional outbox](https://microservices.io/patterns/data/transactional-outbox.html) pattern.

Alternatively you can keep the synchronous communication and implement some retry functionality and if the `Permissions` service is still not available you report error back to the user (but usually it is less preferable option).

Comment: Worth noting that if you're going to have the synchronous communication for a core part of a microservice's functionality, it's worth considering why you have two separate microservices.